# What is a shortcut for window menu bar in GNOME shell?

Tags: window, menu, gnome-shell

I can't find any documentation or tips for shortcut, that will show menu bar as follows:

[image: window menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> is the shortcut you're looking for (<kbd>Super</kbd> is usually the key with Windows logo).

Comment: Thanks, now i see it in settings -> keyboard (application menu) , but it doesn't work even for custom shortcut. Ubuntu 18.04 daily build + pixel saver + ubuntu dock.

Comment: @up-to-you I don't completely understand... did you change super+F10 to another custom shortcut and the new custom shortcut not working? In that case two possible reasons: 1. your new shortcut conflicts with something else, 2. it's a bug, possible as 18.04 is still beta, then report it to launchpad.net.